# Best way to manage OBE contacts and Emails - and personalize emails with CMS Pages

Tags: audience-manager, outbound-email

I have 2 questions about Tridion R5

Question No. 1:

Currently we are using the OBE as following :

a) Create a component in Contents folder

b) Create a page in pages folder

c) Import the contacts from Excel sheet into the Audience Manager address book (we are using only 1 address book)

d) Create a keyword for those contacts in categories and keywords, and import the keyword from the excel sheet into the audience manager (Address Book)

e) Create a Distribution List, and filter the contacts using the keyword previously created

f) Finally, create a mailing and send the email

After sometime using, and important thousands of contacts, I noticed OBE is becoming very slow when testing or sending an email + generating a lot of errors. Just sending an email can require hours and 10 - 20 tries till it's send .. and it does matter it's sending directly in one batch or multiple ones.

My question: Is this a good practice ? How it can be handled if contacts comes to me always in excel sheets, and it might be duplicated in multiple files (same emails to be duplicated in different files).

Question No. 2:

Within the sent email, we are mentioning the customer name + email and may mention any other variables or personalized data. Some email might contain a link to apply or register, the form of the registration surely will contain basic information e.g. Name, Email ..

I was thinking, why would he need to re-enter his name and email address, in the time that I already have it, and I already told him (Hi Customer Name!). It seems illogical to me.

My 2nd question: How can I pass the name, email and other variables from the email into the Tridion created page (register.aspx), knowing that I can have it done manually by adding encrypted query string but still I'm looking for a better generic or standard solution supported by Tridion for this - Maybe a linker between CMS and OBE.

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2):

Your approach seems fine at first glance and Outbound E-mail is certainly capable of handling hundreds of thousands of Contacts. So I'm afraid I would need more information about your setup to know if this approach is leading to your performance problems - or indeed if it can be considered a good practice. Perhaps your issue is unrelated to the way you create your Mailings, but instead are infrastructure related.

I recommend that you contact Customer Support directly, if you haven't done so already.

As for your second question, you should be able to use merge fields in combination with the the query string parameters.